# Excel Help - If two cells meet a certain criteria input a value into another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm a bit of an excel beginner so apologies in advance.
I need my worksheet to automatically input a price into a specific cell.
I have a table in one sheet which has tables for each product brand and then the name and price of each product within the corresponding table.
In the other worksheets I have the product brand in cell H2
and then column B i have the product name, I need the corresponding price for each product to appear in column D. Up until now i have manually been copying them over but this makes it easier to make mistakes and takes more time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! From your explanation, you can use INDEX and MATCH functions to get the expected result.

Comment: You can try the SUMPRODUCT function, you can try to provide a sample table here.

Answer (score 1):

Adapt the following formula to match your columns:

```
=INDEX($C$3:$C$10,MATCH($G3&$H3,$A$3:$A$10&$B$3:$B$10,0))
```

Then, fill the formula down.

[image]

[image]